# Set Vector Layer line-width property to be dependent on attribute with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I am trying to use the QGIS Python API to get the same effect as manually going through the GUI:

> Layer Properties>Symbology>Width>Assistant:

Input:

1. Source = float attribute
2. Hit "Fetch" button

Output:

1. Size from = 0.05
2. to = 3

Opening Layer Properties>Symbology>Width>Edit shows `coalesce(scale_exp("<attribute>", <minValue>, <maxValue>, 0.5, 3, 0.57), 0)` so I tried using it to set the data-defined attribute:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/layer", "VectorLayer", "ogr")
project.addMapLayer(layer)
f_n_index = layer.fields().indexOf('<float attribute>')
max_n_f = network.maximumValue(f_n_index)
min_n_f = network.minimumValue(f_n_index)
n_expression = "coalesce(scale_exp('<float attribute>', " + str(min_n_f) + ", " + str(max_n_f) + ", 0.5, 3, 0.57), 0)"
n_width = QgsProperty.fromExpression(n_expression)
n_prop = network.renderer().symbol().symbolLayers()[0].PropertyWidth
QgsVectorLayer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayers()[0].setDataDefinedProperty(n_prop, n_width))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. However, if I do the manual setup through the GUI, import another layer through the console and then do

```py
GUI_layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayers()[0].copyDataDefinedProperty(console_layer)
```

It works. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: The property seems to be correctly configured and I assume that the expression is correctly formatted. Normally, if something changes in the layer renderer the layer has to be repainted for the changes to be visible. Have you tried to repaint the layer after the change (i.e., ```layer.triggerRepaint()```)?